# PayPal Payment: IPN Http Response Code is empty

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

while checking the paypal ipn history some of the transaction were disabled i resend them but now the http response code is empty for those transactions it should be 200. Searched through paypal documentation but didnt find anything about empty http response code.

i am using a wordpress plugin integrated with paypal api (using adaptive preapproval payment feature)

Comment: Are you using my [PayPal IPN for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/) plugin by chance?

Comment: No I am using fundraising plugin

Comment: So you're entering the IPN URL it gives you, but then the PayPal IPNs getting sent to it are showing a completely empty response code?

Comment: Yes i am using the ipn url according to the plugin documentation but in the ipn history I can see the ipn url for the transaction but there is no response code completely blank was expecting to see some response code to figure out the error

Comment: There must be something going wrong with the IPN script provided by the plugin.  You can check your web server logs to see what's happening when that URL is hit.  You might want to follow these [steps to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/), too.  If you follow that procedure you should be able to pin-point what's going on.

Comment: One more strange thing is happening the ipn url provided by the plugin is not the same when it is displayed it paypal transaction history it's appending a query string like first name last name etc and this is working find before but now payal says that the ipn url is not right which seems to be right before

Comment: They're saying it's "not right" because it's not receiving IPNs correctly.  At least that would be my guess.

Comment: I guess the same thing but plugin behaviour is not always alike it keeps on changing like if for one transaction ipn url is not right but for the next transaction it is right. So this changing behaviour of the transaction for the same plugin is making it hard for me to debug the problem

Comment: I think you're running into confusion with Adaptive IPNs vs. standards IPNs.  Are you acting as the receiver of the payment and the app owner?  If so, you would actually get 2 separate IPNs.  One is app specific and the URL for that would be provided in the NotificationURL parameter of your Pay request.  The other is transaction specific and would be sent to whatever you have setup in your PayPal profile.

Comment: In paypal ipn history how can I distinguish the both ? In plugin settings I have added my paypal email along with app Id information if this is what you are referring too

Comment: may i know @SiDra_1989 which plugin are you using?