# Paypal Business Account on multiple websites

Tags: paypal, wordpress, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a paypal business account and it was working fine but after sometime the ipn starts failing, tried to debug this problem but couldn't figure out what was going wrong. The only different thing I did is using the same paypal business account on multiple websites did this can effect the functionality of paypal ipn?

I am using wordpress fundraising plugin by wpmu

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at this article about [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).  If you follow those procedures you should be able to resolve any issues with the script itself.

Using the same PayPal account on multiple websites isn't a problem, but depending on your invoice ID settings in the accounts and how the payment requests are setup on each site you could have general conflicts.

I would need more info than "IPN is failing" to possibly help more.  Have you checked IPN History in the accounts to see if it's receiving a 200 response from your IPN URL?  What exactly do you mean by "failing"?  Is it just that you're not seeing data updated where you expect to see it, or are you seeing an actual error somewhere?

Help us help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381242/paypal-payment-ipn-http-response-code-is-empty i post this question about the empty request code and this is basically the problem i am facing i thought may be it is because i am using same business accounts on multiple websites